# Unexpected PEM type error When Calling RequestJWTUserToken method of DocuSign C# SDK

Tags: docusignapi, jwt

While retrieving OAuthToken ,despite  providing correct details to the RequestJWTUserToken method, I am confronting "Unexpected PEM type" exception.

I have used correct private key from DocuSign Admin page.

```
OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(INTEGRATOR_KEY, USER_ID, oAuthBasePath, PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES, 1);
```

I am expecting OAuthToken returned but instead I am getting exception. Any help is welcome

Comment: have you generated Private Key from  DocuSign Admin screen under API and Keys section? Also in the Private Key hope you have not removed `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` in the Private Key string.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here for a few people who had these issues and various fixes they did:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/168